# Xamarin Forms: Starting a blocking GC Explicit

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using [this nuget package](https://github.com/nexussays/ble.net) to connect BLE devices.
In debug or release mode after I found many device I got the (error message?) in output window which you can see in the title.

And after that when I want to connect one of them I can't because it's blocking me.

> 05-21 13:14:29.862 I/art     (22207): Starting a blocking GC Explicit
>
> 05-21 13:14:29.897 I/art     (22207): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5355(414KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 48% free, 8MB/16MB, paused 357us total 35.054ms

Somebody can help me?

Comment: Maybe a question for the issues part of its github

Comment: @TheGeneral I tried to found there but nothing :(

Comment: Sign up and ask it, you are probably going to get a quicker answer, failing someone trawling through the code

Comment: @TheGeneral I think it's not the nuget package failure. I mentioned that because I want to add full story of this message. But I already saw this message in the output window before i'm scanning the BLE devices. I'm using to many memory or something? I'm new in little bit new in programming.

Answer (score 0):

`I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed`

It just means the garbage collector is performing as it should.

If this is happening constantly then you have a lot of garbage to free and it could point to a design problem.

In regards to not being able to connect to the devices after this message, well that is question for the authors